# How to Catch variable when data no available

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wan't to make Number of patient registration queue, I have trouble when data registration for today isn't available.

here is my code :

Controllers :

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $data['tbl_pendaftaran'] = $this->m_pendaftaran->getData()->result();
    $data['pasien']=$this->m_pendaftaran->getPasien();
    $data['kpendaftaran']=$this->m_pendaftaran->get_no_pendaftaran();
    //status
    $data['status'] = $this->m_pendaftaran->status()->result();
    $this->template->load('template','pendaftaran/v_pendaftaran',$data);
}
```

Models :

```
function status()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_pendaftaran');
    $this->db->join('tbl_pasien', 'tbl_pendaftaran.id_pasien = tbl_pasien.id');
    $this->db->where('status','menunggu');
    $this->db->limit(1);
    return $this->db->get();
}
```

View :

```
<?php
  foreach ($status as $key ) {
  }
  $cur = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
  if ($key->tgl_berobat<$cur) {
      echo "No Patient for Today";
  } else {
      echo $key->no_antrian;
  }
?>
```

here is result of Error when data for today Isn't available :

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: key
Filename: views/v_pendaftaran.php
Line Number: 22
```

Comment: You didn't have close the foreach loop properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you have typing mistake here or you wrongly closed the foreach loop:

```
<?php
  foreach ($status as $key ) {
  }
  $cur = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
  if ($key->tgl_berobat<$cur) {
      echo "No Patient for Today";
  } else {
      echo $key->no_antrian;
  }
?>
```

TRY THIS:

```
<?php
  foreach ($status as $key ) {

    $cur = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
      if ($key->tgl_berobat < $cur) {
          echo "No Patient for Today";
      } else {
          echo $key->no_antrian;
      }

  }

?>
```

To respond to your comment try this way:

```
<?php

if(isset($status) && !empty($status)){

  foreach ($status as $key ) {

    $cur = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
      if ($key->tgl_berobat < $cur) {
          echo "No Patient for Today";
      } else {
          echo $key->no_antrian;
      }

  }

} else {
    echo "No Patient for Today";
}


//OR 


if(isset($status) && !empty($status)){

  foreach ($status as $key ) {

    $cur = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());

    if(isset($key->tgl_berobat) && !empty($key->tgl_berobat)){
        if ($key->tgl_berobat < $cur) {
          echo "No Patient for Today";
      } else {
          echo $key->no_antrian;
      }
    } else {
          echo "No Patient for Today";
    }
  }

} else {
    echo "No Patient for Today";
}

?>
```

Comment: It's work, but `echo "No Patient for Today"` now show when data isn't available..

Comment: then use `isset` @one_n00b

Answer (score 0):

I think the trouble is in your View. 
Just change the code to

```
<?php
  foreach ($status as $key ) {
      $cur = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
      if ($key->tgl_berobat<$cur) {
          echo "No Patient for Today";
      } else {
          echo $key->no_antrian;
      }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller do not call result function, cause maybe there is no an object to result it.

```
function index()
{
    .
    .
    .
    //status
    $data['status'] = $this->m_pendaftaran->status();
    $this->template->load('template','pendaftaran/v_pendaftaran',$data);
}
```

In your check first if object exist or not:

```
<?php
if($status->num_rows()>0)
{
  foreach ($status->result() as $key ) {

    $cur = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
    if ($key->tgl_berobat<$cur) {
      echo "No Patient for Today";
    } else {
      echo $key->no_antrian;
    }
  }
}
?>
```